# how to save thumbs on S3, using Carrierwave, Fog and hosting on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm using **Carrierwave** to upload images into my app and store it on **S3**. That part is working fine, my issue is when I create a thumbnail of the picture which it does it fine but is storing the thumbnail in **Heroku** instead of **S3**.

**How can I specify to store the thumb on my S3 bucket?**

**Here is my code:**

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  storage :fog

  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  process :set_content_type

  def extension_white_list
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png pdf)
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

   version :thumb do
     process :resize_to_limit => [100, 100]
   end
```

**View:**

```
<%= image_tag doctor.doctor_img_url(:thumb).to_s if doctor.doctor_img? %>
```